# But my deployment is getting failed, due to the exception Could not resolve placeholder 'xd.job.name'

Tags: spring, spring-xd

I'm using spring xd to run a batch job. I want to read the file location in `job.xml` from properties file.
**job.xml**

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:properties/application.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE" />          
    <bean id="readSignOn" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
                <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="SIGNON" />
                <property name="resource" value="file:${file.location}" />
          <property name="unmarshaller" ref="reportUnmarshaller" />
    </bean> 
</context>
```

> DeploymentStatus{state=failed,error(s)=org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'registrar' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring-xd/plugins/job/job-module-beans.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'xd.job.name' in string value "${xd.job.name}"

Comment: <bean id="readSignOn" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
  <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="SIGNON" />
  <property name="resource" value="file:${file.locationChk}" />
  <property name="unmarshaller" ref="reportUnmarshaller" />
 </bean>

Comment: job is defined as above